# Is there an example for integrating Chirp in a Xamarin Android and iOS app?

Tags: chirp

In the article https://blog.chirp.io/chirps-net-sdk-has-been-revamped/ says that the new Chirp SDK .NET 3.6.0 Beta (.NET Standard) is compatible with Xamarin.

Also says that one should "implement their own platform-specific audio I/O for this SDK".
Is there any example of this?
Because in the example "ChipStandardConsoleDemo" provided in the SDK there is no implementation of this.

For a Xamarin app we should go using this .NET SDK or better using the Native Android/iOS Chirp SDKs and build a wrapper/bridge for Xamarin?

Thanks,
Francisco

Answer (score 0):

Francisco,

As discussed in our email discussion, I would recommend to build the wrapper for Xamarin on top of the Android/iOS SDKs has we're experiencing issues breaking the integration with Xamarin, with the current beta version of our .NET SDK.